# getting connection reset after sending a jquery ajax $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making a game lobby with php, jquery, ajax.
I have php echo a string that is a jquery loop that sends ajax $.post's to another page to check and see if some one joined the players game, if new users are online and to get current games to join. if there is then I fill div's on the page with the new data.

here is the loop

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        getPage = function() {
            // this gets all current games users are trying to start up
            $.post("lobbyClasses.php",
            {
                lobbyRequest: "getGames",
            },
            function(data, status){
                if(status == "success"){
                    $("#joinGameContainer").html(data);
                    // this gets all online users and puts themin a div onlineUsers
                    $.post("lobbyClasses.php",
                    {
                        lobbyRequest: "getOnlineUsers",
                    },
                    function(data, status){
                        if(status == "success"){
                            $("#onlineUsers").html(data);
                            // start it again;
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                getPage();
                            }, 5000);
                        }else{
                            // get all online users failed start loop again
                            $("#onlineUsers").html("failed...");
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                getPage();
                            }, 5000);

                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    //get all games failed start loop again
                    $("#joinGameContainer").html("failed...");
                    setTimeout(function(){
                                getPage();
                    }, 5000);
                }
            });
        }
        getPage();
    });
    </script>
```

The problem is that this loop only works sometimes and others the browser(chrome and firefox) will stall and give an error (connection reset in firefox)(no data returned in chrome) I thought that nesting the post request might help and it did significantly but it still happens from time to time. It also happens a lot more when i send another post to a different page such as the following ....

```
$("#makeGame").click(function(){
    getGame = function() {
        $("#scripts").html("getting data...");
        $("#onlineUsers").html("getting data...");
        $("#joinGameContainer").html("getting data...");
        $("#gameContainer").html("getting data...");
        //alert("newgame was clicked.");
        $.post("cardgameclasses.php",
                {
                    gameRequest: "makeGame",
                },
                function(data, status){
                    // the code stalls here and dose nothing then the browser error happens 
                    //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                    if(status == "success"){
                        $("#scripts").html(data);
                    }else{
                        $("#scripts").html("failed...");
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            getGame();
                        }, 5000);
                    }
                });
    }
    getGame();
```

so I thought that replacing the loop with text then sending the post would help and it did a little bit but on occasion i still get a browser error connection reset.  i am not sure what i am doing wrong please help.

Comment: we aren't string parsers, post formatted code that allows syntax highlighting to occur. Also narrow down your issue to specific parts of ythe code. Really not clear what your issue is. Define what you mean by `connection reset`

Comment: do my edits help you to understand my problem better thanks for the help i am new to stack overflow this is my first question i have asked

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was going on with my code PHP only allows so many post vars to a single page to prevent denial of service attacks. I was sending too many posts. I also realized that every thing I was trying to update with ajax could be updated with a single post instead of 4 nested posts. The processing of the data can be done on server side. If you are making several posts for one page you are doing something wrong. The proper code would be this:

```
    function myTimer() {
    $.post("lobbyClasses.php",
    {
        lobbyRequest: "getContent1",
    },
    function(data, status){
        if(status == "success"){
            $("#lobbyContent").html(data);
        }else{
            $("#lobbyContent").html("failed...");
        }
    });
}
myTimer();
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 5000);

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var newarray = [];
var dateandtime = Date.now();
newarray.push(dateandtime); 

function myTimer() {

if( newarray[0] + 1000 < Date.now()){

    $.post("lobbyClasses.php",
    {
        lobbyRequest: "getContent1",
    },
    function(data, status){
        if(status == "success"){
            $("#lobbyContent").html(data);
        }else{
            $("#lobbyContent").html("failed...");
        }
    });
newarray[0] = Date.now();
}
}
myTimer();
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 5000);

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

Comment: That is a lot of code, could you help us understand what it is doing?